# Ajax call best practice: logical error through HTTP error

Tags: ajax, http, http-error

Is there any reason to avoid to send logical error as an HTTP 500 error?
I'm developing a web-app, after an Ajax call I have the default error handler that shows a modal notice with the text of the error.

In some case the error can be logical ('ID not found' or 'The input is not a number' ...), in these cases can I send a HTTP error or it should be reserved only for trasportation/authentication error?

Comment: We also use a default javascript error handler function for jquery ajax in our project. In all cases, we simply return http 500 for server errors. But if it is a handled error on server side, we also return a json object with 500 code, to specify the error type _("warning", "error", "info")_ and error message. Also, either it will be only logged to browser console or will be shown in user interface..

Comment: Thanks Noldor, this is exactly what I want to do. The little trouble (client side) is that the ajax error handler if jquery doesn't parse the Json object automatically like success handler...

Comment: Well, we simply try parsing the "responseText" to json object in the default error callback. If it can not be parsed to json, or it does not contain the required field of the error object, then we simply consider it as an unhandled error and show in dialog in text format. If another ajax process requires a completely different error handling, then we override error callback on that ajax process individually. This approach worked with no problem so fa for us. But I am not sure if it is the best approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is possible from a technical point of view, but I would advise against it. Reason is that you confuse a logical error in the request and a processing error in the processing. Those should be kept separate.

Instead I suggest you use http code `406 Not Acceptable`. It signals that the request has been received, but will not be processed because "it does not make sense". I'd say that is more suitable.

Comment: Ok, I can change the error code according the HTTP standards (40X instead of 500), but is this a good solution to use the HTTP error code or should I return a standard HTTP 200 and, in caso of json response, use a variable such as {error: true, msg:"ID not found"}?

Comment: That again is an old question where there is no right or wrong in my eyes. It is more a philosophical aspect, I'd say. The important thing is to decide for one approach and be consistent in it. And maybe one can say that it depends a bit on the type of API: for a RESTFul service I would prefer http codes, for a more RPC like structure I'd say a consistent status code 200 makes more sense with an embedding of a status inside the payload. But as said: there is no right or wrong.